# Does Zagara benefit from an enemy's Zagara's creep?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

If both teams in a Heroes of the Storm match have a Zagara player, does each Zagara benefit from creep spread by her enemy counterpart?

Put another way: is creep a neutral terrain modifier in this game (as it is in StarCraft), or does creep "belong" to a particular character/team?

Answer (score 4):

You will only benefit from increased movement speed. Similar to StarCraft 2, enemy Zerg units also benefit from the added movement speed from opponent's creep.

Edit - You won't gain the health benefit from the enemy creep - Jeff Noel.

Comment: Additional suggestion for OP, if you press 'C' in game, you get a character details window which explains what 'makes up' your character. You can see regen per second, movement speed, attack speed, etc. You can see what takes place from that =).

Comment: To clarify: You won't gain health regen from enemy creep in Heroes of the Storm.

Comment: @JeffNoel Thanks, I added your info to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a related [Battle.net thread](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/13243934546)